# Live mesh: Remote desktop advanced configuration

Tags: windows-live-mesh

Is there a way to configure Live Mesh Remote Desktop, I do not like this pops up with information that you can log out user if you press ctrl+alt+del (BTW. why I can see it if I'm logged in remotely) and I do not like auto log out after 30 minutes if you do not take any action on remote machine (in other words if you do not click etc. on it for 30 minutes it will automatically log you out, and I want to be connected without time limitation).